# Keep part of the data in memory and part in Disk

Tags: snappydata

I have a column table with millions of records. I would like to keep only the last 3 months in memory, the rest need to be on disk but can be consulted. Is it possible to do this in SnappyData?

Answer (score 0):

Column tables automatically overflow to disk using an LRU algorithm when memory fills up. You can also explicitly configure your eviction settings. All the configuration options are listed [here](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/reference/sql_reference/create-table/#create-table).